# anchor tag or not work in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

### In Menu About us page and contact page not work

```
<li><a href="{{ url('products') }}">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="{{ url('products/about/') }}">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="{{ url('products/contact/') }}">Contact</a></li>
```

home work but About us and contact page not work

### Router

```
Route::resource('/', 'BasicController');
Route::resource('products', 'BasicController');
```

### controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class BasicController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return view('index');
    }

    public function about(){   
       return view('about');
    }

    public function contact()
    {
    return view('contact');
    }
```

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Route::resource` is used for model specific controllers to help generate the routes for CRUD functionality.

To get a route to work for your about page you should use:

```
Route::get('about', 'BasicController@about');
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
<li><a href="{{ url('products/about/') }}">About Us</a></li>
```

Not change products word but let i create anther page

Comment: Route::get('products/about', 'BasicController@about');